# Can I lookup the path to a servlet by name when doing a redirect?

Tags: servlets

I find that

```
response.sendRedirect("/some-path/")
```

Isn't very refactoring tolerant. Is there some equivalent of doing:

```
response.sendRedirect(lookupPath("NameOfMyServlet"))
```

I.e. looking up the path to the servlet rather than hard coding it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can *forward* to a named servlet instead of redirecting, `ServletContext.getNamedDispatcher(String name)` is what you need. It's javadoc says:

> `RequestDispatcher getNamedDispatcher(String name)`
>
> Returns a `RequestDispatcher` object that acts as a wrapper for the named servlet.

Assuming `sc` is the current servlet context (you can get it from the request object):

```
sc.getNamedDispatcher("NameOfMyServlet").forward(request, response);
```

will pass the control to the servlet.

But if you really need to do a redirect, you can only redirect to an URL, and there is no direct way to know what URL a named servlet will process.

So the alternative ways are:

- store *somewhere in your app* a mapping {servletname: path} and use it to find the path to use
- map your servlet to a *technical* path that will never be used elsewhere in the application, in addition to its normal paths and use that technical path for your internal redirection - the bad new, it that this technical path will be displayed in the URL bar of the browser...

Comment: I definitely don't want to forward it. I just figured there would be some way of retrieving the information that's already defined in the @WebServlet  annotation or web.xml, the server must be somewhat aware of these things surely.